# Which piece of data should I choose in univariate analysis

Tags: univariate

What I want is to use univariate analysis to initially identify variables with significant effects for subsequent multivariate analysis.And this is a retrospective study.The data structure is shown in the following figure.

[image: data structure]

In this data,each patient has serveral ECTs,because in the reailty,people would be treated by medicines such as A,B,C,D,etc. After treated,people should do ECG to show if their QTC is larger than a standard value,which the standard is self-choosing. In this case,patient whose QTC>450 is considered to have achieved the outcome.This is why each patient has several observations.

The variates "age","gender","natrium","potassium",the last two are from blood electrolyte test,are less concerned about,"exposure" ,which includes medicines patient treated,is more concerned about.

what I know is that the univariate analysis is to inspect the relationship between variables and outcomes.If we want to do a univariate analysis,we need to calculate the number of the "exposure" equals to A or B or C or D,in this case and "target" equals 0 or 1 seperately.Then my question raised that how to calculate the "exposure" equals to A,for example?

I mean the 5 variates(age,gender,natrium,potassium,exposure) need to be inspected the relationship with outcome,that is,between age and outcome,between gender and outcome,between natrium and outcome,...between exposure and outcome.I would do 5 times univariate analysis,not 5 variates togther with outcome.

I hope I explain clearly this time.

Comment: Please provide more information about your data and the question you are trying to answer with it. For example: explain what the variables are, why you have three observations per patient, why do you want to do univariate analysis, ....

Comment: Albeit your efforts, the post is in my opinion still confusing: "I want is to use univariate analysis to initially identify variables with significant effects for subsequent multivariate analysis". Explain by _modifying_ your post: what do you mean by univariate analysis/multivariate analysis? What are the variables you trying to learn from the data?

Comment: It is very difficult to see any way in which a univariate analysis of anything (which, by definition, examines values of a *single* variable) could possibly provide information about effects on (or any relationship with) any other variable.  Your characterization of univariate analysis as "inspect the relationship between variables and outcomes" is a *multivariate* analysis, leading us to wonder what you really mean by "univariate."  Could you clarify?

Comment: Is it possible that you mistook bivariate analysis with univariate analysis?